# Help with correct php syntax

Tags: php, function, wordpress

I was working on some php functions and I got confused with php syntax.
Here is the function.

Is this correct? to use add_filter inside function_exists check

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'disable_password_reset' ) ) :
  function disable_password_reset() {
    return false;
  }
  add_filter ( 'allow_password_reset', 'disable_password_reset' );
endif;
```

or this one is correct, to use add_filter outside function_exists check

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'disable_password_reset' ) ) :
  function disable_password_reset() {
    return false;
  }
endif;
add_filter ( 'allow_password_reset', 'disable_password_reset' );
```

I was working on Wordpress if that matters.

Comment: Second or first. First ensures your filter uses this very function definition and not an existing one. Second uses any function definition but may double your filter. Make sure you include_once / require_once the file :)

Comment: @Claudrian Hm? How would the second one _double_ the filter? It won't use _any_ function definition, there's only one function definition for `disable_password_reset`, either an existing one or the newly created one (but not both).

Comment: YannisRizos yes, you are right. It wont use both definitions because the way function is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is:

- Check if function `disable_password_reset()` exists, and if not, create it.
- Hook `disable_password_reset()` to a Wordpress filter.

If you do this:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'disable_password_reset' ) ) :
  function disable_password_reset() {
    return false;
  }
  add_filter ( 'allow_password_reset', 'disable_password_reset' );
endif;
```

then `add_filter ( 'allow_password_reset', 'disable_password_reset' );` will *not* be executed if `disable_password_reset()` already exists. If you don't want that, then you should call `add_filter()` outside the `if` block, as in your second example.

Comment: OK. Let me explain what I understood, if a function doesn't exist then it does not matter which one I use, both will work fine and work exactly same. The only difference is when a function already exist. Is the right?

Comment: @Roberthue `function_exists()` is typically used when you have at least a rough idea of what the function does, and you have some reason to believe it might not exist. For example I only remember using it to check for native functions, that although existed in the version of PHP I used locally, they might not exist in one of the various environments my code would be deployed in (and if it actually didn't exist, I either thrown an error or - as you do - emulated the function).

Comment: @Roberthue Now I don't know what the actual `disable_password_reset()` is supposed to do, but it probably isn't just `return false`. The filter will work with either function, the actual one and the emulated one, but obviously it won't work in exactly the same way.

Comment: Actually there is no function named disable_password_reset() and I custom create it to disable what Wordpress does by default if someone rest password (it resets user password). And I don't want users to reset password, that's why I added return false, to do nothing when someone hit password reset button.

Comment: @Roberthue If there's no function called `disable_password_reset()` then why are you checking if it exists in the first place?

Comment: Because I read somewhere today, that it's always best to check it. Is this bad practice? I know the function is not defined because I always have a prefix (ex: robert_) in each custom function (that I created) to make sure, they do not conflict with any other existing function.

Comment: @Roberthue Wow! That's a terrible practice, it's a complete waste of time to check if _every_ function exists, only check when you have some reason to believe that the function might be missing (for example: a WP native function that's not available to all WP versions you're targeting). Even if there is a conflict, PHP will throw a warning when you try to re-define the function.

Comment: you are right and I was doing the same. I didn't check for custom functions that I know Wordpress does not have in core. But I think I misunderstood the concept after reading some articles on net. I am learning PHP basics. BTW Thank you for explain this to me and for your time of course. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Roberthue You're welcome ;) Oh, and since you asked this on Programmers originally, Programmers would be the perfect place to ask about the concepts, but not so much about implementation specifics, those questions are more suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, I think that's why it was moved here. I thought it was related to PHP programming, so should ask in programming section. lol :)

Comment: @Roberthue Yes that's why it was migrated here, I was about to migrate it myself (I'm also a mod on Programmers) but ChrisF was too fast for me ;) Check out our [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq), we are also about programming, but the conceptual side of it, the technical side is what Stack Overflow is for. More details on: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)